# Minimum number of bits to prevent hash collisions?

Tags: hash

There are a number of hashing functions in wide spread use now. Seems the general range of bits is from 128 (MD5) to 512 (SHA-2).

To prevent different types of hash collisions, what are the recommended & minimum number of bits?

Collisions:

- Identifiers (PGP keys, bitcoin addresses, etc...)
- Files (integrity checks)
- HMAC (transmission integrity)
- ?

Comment: With HMAC and file integrity check collision is usually not the problem which need to get addressed. Identifiers are different but here it depends on how many identifiers in total you expect. In other words: collision is not the problem for two of your options and amount of resistance required is impossible to say without more details for the third option. Maybe you should ask instead a real problem you actually have with enough detail.

Comment: What application do you have in mind?

Comment: @Cowthulhu I don't have a specific problem in mind. I've been writing software for a long time and generally their are space requirements (minimum size) or future-proofing (recommended size) for tasks like de-duping files or referencing all possible ids. Having a reference of bit-sizes like this would be helpful.

Comment: @Xeoncross: Note that de-duping files would require resistance against accidental collision (which is different from collisions on purpose). But de-duping is not the same as file integrity which you mention in your question and it also has different requirements. In other words: the actual requirements depend on the actual problem and there is no general rule.

Answer (score 3):

Any unbroken *n*-bit cryptographic hash function has a collision resistance of 2<sup>*n*/2</sup>. This means that, if you want to have a 2<sup>128</sup> collision resistance, you need to use, at minimum, a 256-bit hash function. As 2<sup>64</sup> operations are achievable, you would not want to use a 128-bit hash. A 160-bit hash (that is, a 2<sup>80</sup> security level) is borderline. Using a 256-bit hash will give you a 2<sup>128</sup> security level, which should be completely fine for the foreseeable future. Sometimes, weaknesses in the hash function itself result in it being easier to break than the output digest would suggest. The SHA-2 family of hashes is one example that is currently unbroken. SHA-1 on the other hand [is broken](https://shattered.io/). It has a 160-bit output but "only" a 2<sup>63</sup> security level against collisions, rather than 2<sup>80</sup>.

I suspect you may be mixing up collision attacks with other types of attacks. A collision attack will not allow an attacker to find input that hashes to an arbitrary value. The formal definitions:

- **Preimage attack** - Given *h* where *f(m) = h*, find any *m'* such that *f(m') = h*.

  "Find input that hashes to an arbitrary value."
- **2nd preimage attack** - Given *f(m) = h*, find any *m'* such that *m ≠ m'* and *f(m') = h*.

  "Modify an input without changing the resulting hash."
- **Collision attack** - Find any pair of *m* and *m'* such that *m ≠ m'* and *f(m) = f(m')*.

  "Find any two inputs that have the same hash."

Each attack has different implications. A collision attack is problematic for certificates, as they can be used in signatures that are valid for both benign and malicious versions of the same software. A preimage attack is problematic for verification. Imagine if an attacker could modify an executable without changing its hash. Clearly, a preimage attack is far more severe than a collision attack, but it is also thankfully far more difficult to pull off. The infamously insecure MD4 algorithm, for example, is so bad at collision resistance that it is cheaper to find a collision than it is to run the hash function itself twice. However, as broken as it is, preimage attacks against it are highly theoretical.

If, on the other hand, you simply want to check for *accidental* corruption and are not intending to protect against an active attacker, then a CRC with a properly-selected polynomial would be ideal. A CRC can actually [guarantee error detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks#Error_detection_strength) up to a point.

Comment: You should probably include the mention that this is when no known weaknesses exist in the hash function.  SHA-1 is a 160-bit hash function, but the Shattered Attack took "only" 2^63 operations to find a collision.

Answer (score 2):

A perfect hashing algorithm will output random bits for any unique input. Assuming a perfect hashing algorithm and an infinite amount of memory, the number of hashes you can generate before you will (on average) observe a duplicate, is around `1.2*sqrt(2^bits)`. A hashing algorithm with a *digest length* of 32 bits, will probably produce a duplicate after 77000 hashes. Or, if you want to have a chance of only 0.0001% that you find a duplicate, you may only generate 93 hashes using that algorithm. That's definitely possible with current hardware.

An algorithm with 64 bits output can already be used for over 6 million outputs before you have a chance higher than 0.0001% that a duplicate is produced. But still, 6 million we can do.

So to have a high level of confidence and still being able to generate as many hashes as you like, you need a certain number of bits. But how many bits you need depends on what confidence level you want to achieve. 128 bits is a good level for almost anything.

Another consideration is resilience against attacks. Often, an algorithm is not completely broken but only weakened more and more, until it becomes feasible to do realistic attacks in real-time (if ever). If your hashing algorithm is weakened, you will still want to have enough confidence remaining. That's why most protocols output a little more than necessary, such as 256 bits.

More about the math: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack

Comment: I think OP is specifically asking about attacks, not accidental collisions (in which case a CRC is likely the way to go, since it can, depending on the polynomial, guarantee a different output for a certain number of changed bits in the input). Also oops, I think my editing the math notation messed up a simultaneous edit. Didn't realize you had just posted this!

Comment: @forest I am talking about attacks. If someone has a reasonable chance of generating collisions after doing a bunch of hashing operations (still assuming infinite memory), then they can attack it... And as for math notation (your edit), I prefer code notation because it's more clear, particularly when there's no LaTeX mode available and it's just makeshift with superscript and unicode.

Comment: Thank you! I'm interested in both. Attacks simply cause accidental collisions to be more likely by adding intelligence to interfere with randomness.

Comment: I believe your first sentence is incorrect. A secure (unclear if this is what you mean by "perfect") hash function's output ("digest") is *deterministic* (not random) for any given input, is difficult to generate a *preimage* for (can't take a digest and produce a message that hashes to that digest), and difficult to produce a collision for (can't find two different messages that have the same digest). **However, that does not require that the digest be unpredictable (random)!** For example, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack

Comment: @CBHacking I tried to keep it understandable. If you find a hashing algorithm which gives output that does not look like very high entropy (i.e. random bits), it can definitely be broken. By saying "for any *unique* input" I tried to make clear that it is deterministic, i.e. unique (new) input will give you a new output, and that output is unpredictable in the sense that it looks random (a change in one bit of input, will not give you a chance of one bit in output). I could have phrased it more correctly, but I think that would have been at the cost of length and readability.